# To show that the set $A = \{ (x,y) : x,y \in \Bbb R, x \notin \Bbb Q$ or $y \notin \Bbb Q \} $ is neither open nor compact in $\Bbb R^2$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

To show that the set $A = \{ (x,y) : x,y \in  \Bbb R, x \notin \Bbb Q$ or $y \notin \Bbb Q \} $ is neither open nor compact in $\Bbb R^2$.

To show neither open nor compact in $\Bbb R^2$ is same as showing neither open nor closed or not bounded. It can be easily seen that the set is not bounded. Let us take a point $a = (c,d)$ form $A$ and let us take $d \notin \Bbb Q$. If we take any open ball around $a$ due to density of rationals and irrationals in $\Bbb R$ we can always find a point $(e,f)$ such that both $e,f$ are either rationals or irrationals. Thus the set $A$ is not open.

Is the construction of proof correct??

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Though, just as a matter or wording, you are trying to show it is "neither open nor closed *and* bounded" (though maybe that wording is just as confusing, the point of course is that you have to show it is not open, and you have to either show it is not closed or not bounded)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have shown $A$ is not bounded, not open and not closed. Therefore, your proof is correct.

Comment: the argument can be easily modified to show that the set is not closed (by starting with examining a point in $A^c$ and using the same fact about density), but technically this has not been demonstrated.